# Multicast and ICMP6

Tags: ipv6, multicast

I want to create a socket for receiving ICMP6 packets - to be more precise Neighbor Solicitation Messages that are sent to multicast address ff02::1:ff00:0000/104.

The problem is that when I'm using a socket that I created like this...

```
fd = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6);
```

... I obviously only get to receive these messages if my interface is in the right group (as determined by the target address of the NS message).

The question is: How do I get my socket to read ALL ICMP6 messages, no matter which multicast group they are sent to?

I had hoped IPV6_JOIN_GROUP with a zero-ed address field would work (some implementations allows this to join all groups), but Linux doesn't support this.

Is this possible to achieve without having to switch from IPPROTO_ICMPV6?

Comment: Not possible due to design of multicast.  If you limit your requirements you could hack something.  For example using a network hub or network switch with mirror port and using promiscuous mode to read all network traffic.